# failed to select a version for `zstd-sys`

Tags: substrate-node-template

````
```sh
    error: failed to select a version for `zstd-sys`.
        ... required by package `zstd-safe v4.1.1+zstd.1.5.0`
        ... which satisfies dependency `zstd-safe = "=4.1.1"` of package `zstd v0.9.0+zstd.1.5.0`
        ... which satisfies dependency `zstd = "^0.9.0"` of package `sp-maybe-compressed-blob v4.1.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.18#fc3fd073)`
        ... which satisfies git dependency `sp-maybe-compressed-blob` of package `sc-executor-common v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.18#fc3fd073)`
        ... which satisfies git dependency `sc-executor-common` of package `sc-executor v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.18#fc3fd073)`
        ... which satisfies git dependency `sc-executor` of package `sc-client-api v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.18#fc3fd073)`
        ... which satisfies git dependency `sc-client-api` of package `sc-block-builder v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.18#fc3fd073)`
        ... which satisfies git dependency `sc-block-builder` of package `sc-finality-grandpa v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.18#fc3fd073)`
        ... which satisfies git dependency `sc-finality-grandpa` of package `sc-finality-grandpa-rpc v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.18#fc3fd073)`

``
````

Comment: Please include a way to reproduce this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

use `cargo update` command or Make the dependencies compatible with other in the `cargo.toml`